# What do we use in Azure Dev a project or pipelines per solution

Tags: azure-devops, nuget, azure-pipelines

Help needed with azure pipelines. Just testing it and consider migrating from TeamCity to Azure Dev and was wondering:

I have:

```
1. Asp.Net Core Web Api (Web1)
2. Asp.Net Core Web Api (Web2) 
3. WPF App
4. Several infrastructure class libraries that are shared libs between the above 3 solutions (Web1, Web2, WPF).
```

Do I create 4 azure projects?

```
1 project that includes the repository of Web1 project with 1 pipeline that nuget restores, builds and publish artifacts 
1 project that includes the repository of Web1 project with 1 pipeline that nuget restores, builds and publish artifacts 
1 project that includes the repository of WPF App with 1 pipeline that nuget restores, builds and publish artifacts 
1 project that includes all repositories of all class libs and for each library I create a pipeline
```

or I create one project for all and add one pipeline for each (web1, web2, wpf apps and class libs)

Comment: Are those .NET projects located on different git repositories? Is your git tool Github or Azure Devops repos? Personally I use projects to seperate different logical projects (development teams) and different pipelines inside the same project for different projects of the team. For example team A could have 4 projects, I would go for one DevOps project and 4 pipelines inside it. Team B would have a separate project

Comment: Yes all of them are on different repositories. Even each library has its own github repository. I use Github. Understood I will create 3 projects for web1, web2 and wpf but what about the shared libraries?

Comment: Shared libraries can be handled the same way as different projects. You can build them and upload them through a task on nuget. If they should be included on the projects, there should be already on your web1,web2 and wpf projects, as a result the pipeline that will execute msbuild and nuget restore will handle the libraries also

Comment: Yes that is how it is working now in TeamCity. I build them, pack them and push on a private nuget feed. Question is do I add them all in a project and create a pipeline for each library or create one project per library and inside each project create one pipeline?

Comment: This should highly depend on the accesses you want to provide (people). If you do not want to eliminate some projects to specific people, then I would go for one DevOps projects and different pipelines for each library project. In general you combine the pipeline with a github repository. As a result if all your libraries are placed inside one github repository you will go with one pipeline, else you have to create multiple pipelines inside the same Azure Devops Project

Comment: great thank you. You can write this as an answer

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/projects/about-projects?view=azure-devops#when-to-add-another-project provides some good examples of pros and cons of multiple projects vs teams and how to scale an Azure DevOps organization in general

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Writing the comments as an answer so that we can close the question.*

Are those .NET projects located on different git repositories? Is your git tool Github or Azure Devops repos?

Personally I use projects to seperate different logical projects (development teams) and different pipelines inside the same project for different projects of the team.

For example team A could have 4 projects, I would go for one DevOps project and 4 pipelines inside it. Team B would have a separate project etc.

Shared libraries can be handled the same way as different projects. You can build them and upload them through a task on nuget. If they should be included on the projects, there should be already on your web1,web2 and wpf projects, as a result the pipeline that will execute msbuild and nuget restore will handle the libraries also.

If you do not want to eliminate some projects to specific people, then I would go for **one** DevOps project and **different** pipelines for each library project.

In general you combine the pipeline with a github repository. As a result if all your libraries are placed inside one github repository you will go with one pipeline, else you have to create multiple pipelines inside the same Azure Devops Project.

In general the approach that I mainly use:

```
Different Azure DevOps projects -> Different dev teams.
Projects inside one dev team -> Different pipelines inside the project.
Different github repositories -> Different pipelines for each one (exceptions apply here but in most cases it is a practice)
```